# In JWASM/MASM - pshufw produces Error A2030: Instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, sse, mmx

I have the following assembly program that gives me an error when compilating:

```
.686
.mmx
.model flat,c
.code

MmxAdd  proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    mov eax, [ebp+24]        
    cmp eax, AddOpTableCount      
    jae BadAddOp                

    movq mm0,[ebp+8]             
    movq mm1,[ebp+16]       
    jmp [AddOpTable+eax*4]       

MmxPaddb:
    paddb mm0,mm1            
    jmp SaveResult

MmxPaddsb:
    paddsb mm0,mm1               
    jmp SaveResult  

MmxPaddusb:
    paddusb mm0,mm1             
    jmp SaveResult

MmxPaddw:
    paddw mm0,mm1             
    jmp SaveResult

MmxPaddsw:
    paddsw mm0,mm1             
    jmp SaveResult  

MmxPaddusw:
    paddusw mm0,mm1           
    jmp SaveResult

MmxPaddd:                       
    paddd mm0,mm1
    jmp SaveResult

BadAddOp:
    pxor mm0,mm0

SaveResult:
    movd eax,mm0                   
    pshufw mm2,mm0, 01001110b       
    movd edx,mm2                   
    emms                           

    pop ebp
    ret

    align 4                                            

AddOpTable:
    dword MmxPaddb, MmxPaddsb, MmxPaddusb
    dword MmxPaddw, MmxPaddsw, MmxPaddusw
    dword MmxPaddd

AddOpTableCount equ ($-AddOpTable) / size dword

MmxAdd  endp
    end
```

But every time I try to compile it with JWASM I get the following error:

> Mmx_Addition.asm(51) : Error A2030: Instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode

That is the instruction that give me the error:

```
pshufw mm2,mm0, 01001110b
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pshufw` is considered an [SSE(SSE-1) instruction](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15740-f02/public/doc/discussions/uniprocessors/media/mpr_p3_mar99.pdf). The instruction was considered an an extension to MMX aka [MMXEXT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_MMX), and to use it you will have to enable SSE using the `.xmm` directive instead of `.mmx`. This should work:

```
.686
.xmm
.model flat,c
.code
```

`.xmm` also implies `.mmx` so you don't need both. If you do use both then `.mmx` has to come before `.xmm`. I don't recommend using both.

---

The other instructions added as MMX extensions with SSE-1 were:

- `PINSRW`

  Insert 16-bit value from general register into one of four elements (specified by immediate)
- `PEXTRW`

  Extract one of four elements (specified by immediate) to a general register
- `PMULHU`

  Multiply four 16-bit unsigned elements returning most significant 16 bits of each
- `PSHUFW`

  Full shuffle of 16-bit elements under control of 8-bit immediate mask
- `PMOVMSB`

  Move 8-bit mask composed of MSbs of byte elements to a general register
- `PAVGB`

  Average of byte elements (Di = –(Di+ Si + 1)/2, i = 0…7)
- `PAVGW`

  Average of 16-bit elements (Di = –(Di + Si + 1)/2, i = 0…3)
- `PSADBW`

  Sum of absolute value of differences of 16-bit elements (D1,0 = ∑i=0…3 |Di – Si|)
- `PMINSW`

  Minimum of signed 16-bit elements
- `PMINUB`

  Minimum of unsigned byte elements
- `PMAXSW`

  Maximum of signed 16-bit elements
- `PMAXUB`

  Maximum of unsigned byte elements

---

You must use `.686` (or later) alongside `.xmm` for `.xmm` directive to work as expected.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much!
Actually I'm following a MASM course and I don't understand why in Visual Studio the professor of the course doesn't need to write processor type directive and the "mmx" + "xmm" directives to make the program compile, but if in Jwasm I don't add them the program doesn't compile. Do you know why? Is because Visual Studio automatically add them in compilation time? Thank you so much! You're really saving my day by answering all my MASM questions xD You're really good with it!

Comment: @Z3R0 : I believe that with MASM 8.xx in Visual Studio 2005 (and later releases) that the default is CPU with SSE2/MMX/686 capabilities. Prior to that I believe the default was an 8086 with an 8087 coprocessor (no MMX or SSE/SSE2). JWASM isn't MASM but a close clone. If you want JWASM to default to a similar CPU model as MASM in Visual Studio I recommend passing the option `-9` when assembling with JWASM. As well if this answer solved your problem please remember to accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you really much! I will try it! Now I'll try the answer too!

Comment: yes sorry how do I accept as an answer?

Comment: found it silly me xD